# See SQL Statements/Query Params in IIS logs?

Tags: iis, webserver

I'm working on an application that analyses web server logs to detect SQL injection attacks. I've been able to parse Apache logs and extract SQL statements because they are included in the requests' query params like so:

```
84.55.41.57- - [14/Apr/2016:08:22:13 0100] "GET /wordpress/wp-content/plugins/custom_plugin/check_user.php?userid=1 AND (SELECT 6810 FROM(SELECT COUNT(*),CONCAT(0x7171787671,(SELECT (ELT(6810=6810,1))),0x71707a7871,FLOOR(RAND(0)*2))x FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_SETS GROUP BY x)a) HTTP/1.1" 200 166 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
```

To do this I had to enable query strings in the access logs. Is there a way I can see SQL statements from IIS logs as well? I haven't been able to find anything helpful so far and am not even sure what to search. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If sql statements are included in query parameters, IIS will record query strings by default.

[image]

The format of log is:

```
2020-08-21 05:33:50 127.0.0.1 GET /blog.aspx id=23 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/84.0.4147.135+Safari/537.36 - 500 51 1413 0
```

By the way, [IIS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/filteringrules/#configuration-sample) has provided a sample about how to prevent SQL injection attacks. You can refer to it.

```
<requestFiltering>
<filteringRules>
  <filteringRule name="SQLInjection" scanUrl="false" scanQueryString="true">
     <appliesTo>
        <clear />
        <add fileExtension=".asp" />
        <add fileExtension=".aspx" />
        <add fileExtension=".php" />
     </appliesTo>
     <denyStrings>
        <clear />
        <add string="--" />
        <add string=";" />
        <add string="/*" />
        <add string="@" />
        <add string="char" />
        <add string="alter" />
        <add string="begin" />
        <add string="cast" />
        <add string="create" />
        <add string="cursor" />
        <add string="declare" />
        <add string="delete" />
        <add string="drop" />
        <add string="end" />
        <add string="exec" />
        <add string="fetch" />
        <add string="insert" />
        <add string="kill" />
        <add string="open" />
        <add string="select" />
        <add string="sys" />
        <add string="table" />
        <add string="update" />
     </denyStrings>
     <scanHeaders>
        <clear />
     </scanHeaders>
  </filteringRule>
```